# Excel formula to replace value based on corresponding table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to find a solution to my problem in Excel.

I have a "Input values" table that has different values on each row, text / content that includes different colors.

[image]

I also have a "Corresponding values" table: for specific colors, i have a corresponding value in column D.

I am trying to get to a solution in Excel that can give me the results in "Output values" table. Ideally the excel formula for each row would give me the results found in output values table.

i.e. "green" would be replaced with "color 1", so the final result is "color 1 and dark" .

I have tried a few ways with substitute and index formulas but without success; it only worked for the first 1-2 rows of the input values table.

Ideally, it'd be great if the formula would work without VBA code.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you show some of your attempts to solve this?

Comment: yes sure, this is the formula i tried in cell B8:

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,INDEX(C2:C4,1),INDEX(D2:D4,1)),INDEX(C2:C4,2),INDEX(D2:D4,2))

Comment: @DougLasore What's wrong with that? Seems to work?

Comment: @Tom I think the issue is with the 3rd input: `blunt yellowish darkblue red` is being replaced with `blunt color 2ish darkblue red`

Comment: @JustynaMK I tried @DougLasore formula and it returned the 3rd value as `blunt yellowish darkblue color 3`

Comment: @Tom Might be that you didn't lock the ranges, i.e. you used `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A4,INDEX(C4:C6,1),INDEX(D4:D6,1)),INDEX(C4:C6,2),INDEX(D4:D6,2))` instead of `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A4,INDEX($C$2:$C$4,1),INDEX($D$2:$D$4,1)),INDEX($C$2:$C$4,2),INDEX($D$2:$D$4,2))`

Comment: here are the results i got:
B8 = https://imgur.com/ORUoSd7
B9 = https://imgur.com/D3FBvIG
B10 =https://imgur.com/SX0MI5a
B11 = https://imgur.com/qIKzGXA

you can see it works for B8 and B9, but it does not work for B10 & B11. i am not sure why.. maybe because the word is not at the beginning of the cell (i.e. "red" is at the end)

Comment: i did try to lock the ranges with $, and i also tried to give a name to range , but i got same results, it works on some cells but not on all

Comment: @DougLasore thanks for the screenshots, this is useful. It looks like you didn't include a case for `red` in your formula, you only have two substitutes (for `green` and `yellow`) - `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"green","color 1"),"yellow","color 2")`

Comment: hi all, thanks a lot for helping me with this. i realize what my issue is. 

I am actually trying to find a good working Excel formulat that can be aplied for this whole range, not just 3 colors; i might have 50 colors there for instance: https://imgur.com/Kmjejqf

I've put together the excel sheet to be more helpful if anyone is interested : https://www.dropbox.com/s/wccf1fdtf9i0izm/stackoverflow%20excel%20template%20substitute.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Just updated the excel sheet to include the full range, this makes more sense now: https://imgur.com/DpO5Q22 . please re-download the excel sheet if you got the first version.

Comment: It looks like the answer provided by shrivallabha.redij is working, give it a try.

Comment: yes, all good, the solution provided by shrivallabha.redij is great and working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one color replacement, you can try below formula.

Setup:

`A2` holds input value.

Range `E2:F4` contains the substitution matrix

Formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&$E$2:$E$4&" "," "&A2&" ",1),$E$2:$E$4),LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&$E$2:$E$4&" "," "&A2&" ",1),$F$2:$F$4))
```

Comment: +1 Very nice approach. I like that it doesn't convert `yellowish` to `color 2ish` as in the original formula.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij just wondering if you ever tried this: if i try to add the substitution matrix in another sheet (Sheet 2), the formula does not work. So... is it a requirement to have the substitution matrix in the same sheet with the formula? just wondering, thanks

Comment: a very nice answer especially it does not require CSE! would you mind briefly explain the use of LOOKUP in this case or point out a direction to understand how you used it? much appreciated!

Comment: I think I just worked it out! It should be safe to replace `2^15` with `LEN(A2)` if I understand your use of LOOKUP correctly. :)

Comment: @DougLasore it should still work. I do not see any issue if you have it on second sheet. e.g. `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4&" "," "&A2&" ",1),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4),LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4&" "," "&A2&" ",1),Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4))` just the same way.

Comment: @TerryW You understood it correctly! 2^15 represents 32768 which is more than the number of characters a cell can hold 32767. I saw the LOOKUP construct by Aladin Akyurek on MrExcel.

Answer (score 0):

The following **array formula** will also return the desired result.

```
{=SUBSTITUTE(" "&A2:A4&" "," "&C2:C4&" "," "&D2:D4&" ")}
```

Highlight `B2:B4`, enter this formula in formula bar and press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to confirm.